# storing a vector in a matrix in r with unknown vector length

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, vector

Hi there i was wondering if is there a way to store a vector into an array or matrix.
 for example,

```
array1<-array(dim=c(1,2))
vector1<-as.vector(1:5)
vector2<-as.vector(6:10)
array1[1,1]<-vector1
array1[1,2]<-vector2
```

so that when i call for

```
array1[1,1]
```

i will receive

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

I've tried doing what i did above and what i get the error

```
 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

is there a way to get around this?

also, the problem that i face is that i do not know the vector length and that the vectors could have different length as well.

i.e vector 1 can be length of 6 and vector 2 can be a length of 7.

thanks!

Comment: What do you want to fill the shorter vector with?

Comment: Use lists instead of arrays if the length is not equal.

Comment: How many dimensions do you want to have in your list? The vector can be stored in a list and retrieved with `my_list[[1]]`, so I'm not sure why you want to use two index numbers `array[1,1]`.

Comment: My problem is that I have 5x4175 vectors of random length that i have to create which will clutter my environment, i would guess that my list should have 5rows and 4175 columns as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try with a list:

```
my_list <- list()
my_list[[1]] <- c(1:5)
my_list[[2]] <- c(6:11)
```

A list allows you to store vectors of varying length. The vectors can be retrieved by addressing the element of the list:

```
> my_list[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Can a list have multiple rows and columns?

Comment: @Donkeykongy A list can contain matrices or data.frames with arbitrary number of rows and columns. But considering this question in the comment I assume that the answer by Roland describes what you are looking for, i.e., a matrix of lists rather than a list of matrices.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a matrix of lists:

```
m <- matrix(list(), 2, 2)
m[1,1][[1]] <- 1:2
m[1,2][[1]] <- 1:3
m[2,1][[1]] <- 1:4
m[2,2][[1]] <- 1:5
m
#     [,1]      [,2]     
#[1,] Integer,2 Integer,3
#[2,] Integer,4 Integer,5

m[1, 2]
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

m[1, 2][[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```